# Constructor in inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

How to declare constructor on class Tanks, in order to create new object, like that:

```
tanks t34(durability, velocity, damage);
```

Here is my class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class vehicles{
private:
    double durability;
    double velocity;
public:
     void drive() { cout << "drive\n"; }
     void info() { cout << durability << " " << velocity << "\n"; }
     vehicles(double d, double v) : durability(d), velocity(v) {}
     ~vehicles() {}
};

class tanks:public vehicles{
private:
    double damage;
public:
    using vehicles::vehicles;
    tanks(double dmg) : damage(dmg) {}
    void shot();
};
```

So i would like to copy variable from:

```
vehicles(double d, double v) : durability(d), velocity(v) {}
```

and add it to class Tanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another constructor in `tanks`:

```
tanks(double dmg, double v, double d):vechicles(d,v), dmanage(dmg) {}
                                    //^^call base class constructor to init base part
```

Then you should be able to create an object of `tanks` as follows:

```
tanks t34(durability, velocity, damage);
```